# Is there an official leaderboard?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo II, when you log in on battle.net, you can see a leaderboard of the characters of the server, ordered by level. Is there something similar for Diablo III? If not in-game at least on a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They probably made this decision because Diablo 3 won't have ladder seasons, meaning that players that are on top are liable to stay there for very long periods of time, and new players will be virtually locked out once the game has been out for a little while.